# Split Json Response body using BeanShell Scripting

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am trying to test REST APIs using JMeter. My lead told me to do load testing on each API using JMeter. Currently I am testing a Get API request, and I am getting the below JSON response body with double quotation.

"https://api.rewards.com:/lists/v1/listcontainer/1?ts=20190221004021&auth=EngineeringSolutions:ydvMMlY2uxiKG0yuwh1IbVgR2mfqTQaQncTEaMr+Ef0="

Now I have to pass this JSON body to another HTTP request and test the API.

My questions:

How can I get the values of ts and auth using split method like (ts=20190221004021 and auth=EngineeringSolutions:ydvMMlY2uxiKG0yuwh1IbVgR2mfqTQaQncTEaMr+Ef0=)
and store them into two different variables and print them on log view.

I am trying to get ts and auth value from the json response using split method. I am able to split the URL into two by using the below code. But, this is not my solution. I want to get 'ts' and 'auth' values and store them in two different variables.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how I can trim and split the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

To parse JSON with JMeter you need to add the [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to your test plan:

1. Right click on your Get API request where you are getting the JSON
2. Add –> Post Processors
3. JSON Extractor.
4. In the `JSON Path expressions` field specify your JSON path to parse the JSON response
5. Set up variables names in `Names of created variables`, for example `ts` and `auth`
6. Use this variables in the next request as: `${ts}` and `${auth}` for example:

   `https://api.rewards.com:/lists/v1/listcontainer/1?ts=${ts}&auth=${auth}=`

Check this article to get more ingormation about JSON and other extractors:
[Using JMeter extractors](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)